# Creating a blog wordpress app with same database as the wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am wondering whether it is possible to create a wordpress app which links to the current wordpress site so the blogs will all be present on the new app. And whether it is possible to do this with minimal / no code involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible there is a plugin available in WordPress which can convert your WordPress site into a native mobile app for iOS and Android phones and tablets, published to App Store and Google Play for you.

Here is the [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mobiloud-mobile-app-plugin/)

and here is a list of some [other plugins](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-site-mobile-app/).

you can also see [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WV--72wm4NM) how can you convert your WordPress site into a native mobile app